# How classes in Adobe Flash Professional works?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I start before 1 year to use CS6 and I found some tutorials that explain how to make pltaformer games, I try a lot of tutorials they work great but for the code they use the timeline.
So, I make a game using the timeline but when I published it and running to my android device I have a lot of lag issues.

After a research I realized that coding in the timeline is a bad idea, also it's better to use Starling for making apps for mobile devices.
So I want to start again to learn how classes working.

I make a new project and I have 5 classes (Main, Level1, Hero, Ground and Enemy). I want the hero to interact with Ground (for gravity) and with Enemy (for hitTest), also Enemy have gravity so they must interact with the Ground.

The concerns are :

- In which class I must write the hitTest function?
- I have to write in `Ground` class the hitTest for `Hero` and the `Enemy` and in the `Hero` class to write the collision between the `Hero` and the `Enemy`
- Or all of this functions must be write in `Main` class?

Comment: Hope that helps: https://forum.starling-framework.org/tags/hittest

Comment: Thank you @Organis but this is the next step for me.For now i just only want to learn how the classes work!

Comment: Oh. Then Google > as3 classes tutorial.

Comment: This question is too broad for the StackOverflow format.  Your best bet is to search the internet on how to learn Classes and Object Oriented Programming in general as Organis suggests.    If you are moving away from the timeline, I'd suggest not using FlashPro at all.  FlashDevelop is free and offers better speed and tooling.    Once you've gotten your feet wet and run into more specific problems, post those questions here and someone will gladly assist!

Comment: I start to watch some tutorials for FlashDevelop, i found some great tutorials  but the guy there use a library call FlashPunk. Is that FlashPunk works like starling? I mean, its ok to use this lib for making games for mobile devices ? It use GPU like starling?